# How do I match multiple regex patterns against a column value in Spark?

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, pattern-matching

I have column :

```
val originalSqlLikePatternMap = Map("item (%) is blacklisted%" -> "BLACK_LIST",
      "%Testing%" -> "TESTING",
  "%purchase count % is too low %" -> "TOO_LOW_PURCHASE_COUNT")

val javaPatternMap = originalSqlLikePatternMap.map(v => v._1.replaceAll("%", ".*") -> v._2)

val df = Seq(
  "Testing(2,4, (4,6,7) foo, Foo purchase count 1 is too low", 
  "Foo purchase count (12, 4) is too low ", "#!@", "item (mejwnw) is blacklisted",
   "item (1) is blacklisted, #!@" 
).toDF("raw_type")

val converter = (value: String) => javaPatternMap.find(v => value.matches(v._1)).map(_._2).getOrElse("Unknown")
val converterUDF = udf(converter)

val result = df.withColumn("updatedType", converterUDF($"raw_type"))
```

but it gives :

```
+---------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
|raw_type                                                 |updatedType           |
+---------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
|Testing(2,4, (4,6,7) foo, Foo purchase count 1 is too low|TESTING               |
|Foo purchase count (12, 4) is too low                    |TOO_LOW_PURCHASE_COUNT|
|#!@                                                      |Unknown               |
|item (mejwnw) is blacklisted                             |BLACK_LIST            |
|item (1) is blacklisted, #!@                             |BLACK_LIST            |
+---------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
```

But I want "Testing(2,4, (4,6,7) foo, Foo purchase count 1 is too low" to give 2 values "TESTING, TOO_LOW_PURCHASE_COUNT" like this :

```
 +---------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|raw_type                                                 |updatedType                     |
+---------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|Testing(2,4, (4,6,7) foo, Foo purchase count 1 is too low|TESTING, TOO_LOW_PURCHASE_COUNT |
|Foo purchase count (12, 4) is too low                    |TOO_LOW_PURCHASE_COUNT          |
|#!@                                                      |Unknown                         |
|item (mejwnw) is blacklisted                             |BLACK_LIST                      |
|item (1) is blacklisted, #!@                             |BLACK_LIST, Unkown              |
+---------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

Can someone tell what I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2):

Ok. So, couple of things here,

1. Regarding `find`, you need to check each `Row` against each regex for your desired output, so find is not the right choice.

   > the first value produced by the iterator satisfying a predicate, if
   >   any.
2. Take care with regex, you've left a space after low, thats why its not matching. May you should reconsider just replacing `%` with `.*` also,

   `%purchase count % is too low %`

So, with the changes, your code will be something like,

```
 val originalSqlLikePatternMap = Map(
      "item (%) is blacklisted%" -> "BLACK_LIST",
      "%Testing%" -> "TESTING",
      "%purchase count % is too low%" -> "TOO_LOW_PURCHASE_COUNT")

    val javaPatternMap = originalSqlLikePatternMap.map(v => v._1.replaceAll("%", ".*").r -> v._2)

    val df = Seq(
      "Testing(2,4, (4,6,7) foo, Foo purchase count 1 is too low",
      "Foo purchase count (12, 4) is too low ", "#!@", "item (mejwnw) is blacklisted",
      "item (1) is blacklisted, #!@"
    ).toDF("raw_type")

    val converter = (value: String) => {
      val res = javaPatternMap.map(v => {
        v._1.findFirstIn(value) match {
          case Some(_) => v._2
          case None => ""
        }
      })
        .filter(_.nonEmpty).mkString(", ")

      if (res.isEmpty) "Unknown" else res
    }

    val converterUDF = udf(converter)

    val result = df.withColumn("updatedType", converterUDF($"raw_type"))

    result.show(false)
```

Output,

```
+---------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|raw_type                                                 |updatedType                    |
+---------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|Testing(2,4, (4,6,7) foo, Foo purchase count 1 is too low|TESTING, TOO_LOW_PURCHASE_COUNT|
|Foo purchase count (12, 4) is too low                    |TOO_LOW_PURCHASE_COUNT         |
|#!@                                                      |Unknown                        |
|item (mejwnw) is blacklisted                             |BLACK_LIST                     |
|item (1) is blacklisted, #!@                             |BLACK_LIST                     |
+---------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: currently the udf is written im a way that if there are no matches, Unknown value is given. If there are multiple regex matches as you asked, they&#39;re returned, like for the top row. Unkown is thus the default value. to make the change to, case None => "Unkown"

Comment: So if there are multiple values it will match and if there is any unknown followed by other matches,.. it won't ?

Comment: yes because there is no unknown specific  rule in javaPatternMap